# Почему мой запрос к api биржи Yobit.net возвращает ошибку 404?

Tags: c#, xnet

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос информации. Следовал всем [инструкциям к апи](https://yobit.net/en/api/), но все равно получаю 404.

Хочу выполнить запрос из TradeApi getInfo. 
POST https://yobit.net/tapi/getInfo?nonce=1
Headers:
Key:{Публичный ключ апи}
Sign: {строка "?nonce=1" закодированная с помощью приватного ключа через  HMAC-SHA512}

В ответ всегда 404. Что не так?

Прилагаю код.
Запрос:

```
public APIResponse Request(string method, Dictionary<string, string> param = null, int ReRequestCount = 3)
{
    lock (locker)
        nonce = IncrementNonce();

    string urlParamStr = "?";
    using (HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest())
    {
        if (param != null)
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in param)
            {
                request.AddUrlParam(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                urlParamStr += pair.Key + "=" + pair.Value + "&";
            }
        request.AddUrlParam("nonce", nonce);
        urlParamStr += "nonce=" + nonce;
        string signedData = Get_HMAC_SHA512_Hash(Sign, urlParamStr);

        request.AddHeader("Key", Key);
        request.AddHeader("Sign", signedData);

        HttpResponse response = request.Post("https://yobit.net/tapi/" + method.ToString());
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (ReRequestCount > 0)
            {
                return Request(method, param, --ReRequestCount);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(response.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

HMAC генератор:

```
public string Get_HMAC_SHA512_Hash(string key, string source)
{
    byte[] secretkeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(secretkeyBytes))
    {
        byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < hashValue.Length; i++)
        {
            s += string.Format("{0:x2}", hashValue[i]);
        }
        return s;
        //return System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api следует вызывать следующим образом:

https://yobit.net/tapi?method=getInfo&nonce=1

Comment: Действительно. интересно, почему этого нет в документации....